# Update a record using VF

Tags: visualforce, update

I am trying to make a VF page that updates a custom object called Time_Sheet__c

I only need a Text box and a save button (that updates the already existing Time sheet)

The problem i am having with my VF page is that it creates a new record rather than updating the Note_for_the_day__c field in the existing record

Here is my VF page so far:

```
    <apex:page standardController="Time_Sheet__c">
<style>.pbSubsection{
width: 400px;}</style>
<apex:form >
  <apex:Pageblock Title="Notes on the Day">
  <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
  <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
  <apex:outputLabel ></apex:outputLabel>  
  <apex:inputField Value="{!Time_Sheet__c.Note_for_the_Day__c}"
 style="height:100px;width:400px;"/>
   </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>   
  <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="save"/>

  </apex:pageBlockSection>

  </apex:Pageblock>

  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

What do I have to change to fix this issue?

EDIT:

Here is the Clock in and Out VF page that creates the record i want to update. Maybe we can just add the text box and update button to this VF page?

```
<apex:page controller="AttendanceController" id="thePage" >
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.slds120,'assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.css')}"/> 
<apex:form id="theForm">
    <apex:inputhidden id="location" value="{!location}"/><br/>
    <article class="slds-card slds-card--narrow">
        <div class="slds-card__header slds-grid">    
            <div class="slds-card__body" >
                <div class="slds-tile__detail slds-text-body--small" >
                    <h2>                            
                            <span class="slds-text-heading--small">Today's Time Sheet</span>                            
                        </h2>
                    <dl class="slds-dl--horizontal" >       

                        <apex:repeat value="{!currUserTimeSheetLst}" var="userTimeSheet">
                             <dt class="slds-dl--horizontal__label" style="display:{!IF(userTimeSheet.Clock_in__c != Null ,'block','None')}">
                            <span class="slds-truncate" title="Checked_In_Time">Checked In Time : <apex:outputfield value="{!userTimeSheet.Clock_in__c }"/></span>
                        </dt>
                        <dt class="slds-dl--horizontal__label" style="display:{!IF(userTimeSheet.Clock_Out__c != Null ,'block','None')}">
                            <span class="slds-truncate" title="Checked_Out_Time">Checked Out Time : <apex:outputfield value="{!userTimeSheet.Clock_Out__c }"/></span>
                        </dt>
                        </apex:repeat>
                    </dl>
                </div>                    

            </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="slds-card__body" >                  
            <apex:commandlink styleClass="slds-button slds-button--neutral" action="{!checkIn}" value="Check In" style="display:{!IF(currUserTimeSheet.Clock_in__c == Null ,'block','None')} "/>
            <apex:commandlink id="CheckOut" styleClass="slds-button slds-button--neutral" action="{!checkOut}" value="Check out" onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure to Check out?')){return false};" style="display:{!IF(currUserTimeSheet.Clock_in__c != Null && currUserTimeSheet.Clock_Out__c == Null,'block','None')} " />                
        </div>            
    </article>
</apex:form>
<script type="text/javascript">    
//error handler
function showError(error) { 
    var strError = "Unknown Error";
    switch(error.code) {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            strError = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
            break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            strError = "Location information is unavailable."
            break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
            strError = "The request to get user location timed out."
            break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            strError = "An unknown error occurred."
            break;
    }
    alert(strError);
    document.getElementById("thePage:theForm:location").value  = strError;

};    
//success handler
function successGeo(position){        
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    lon = position.coords.longitude;        
    var strLatLong = + lat.toString() + ',' + lon.toString();
    document.getElementById("thePage:theForm:location").value  = strLatLong;
};    
// detection capabilities with JavaScript    
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    //alert('Getting Geolocation');        
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successGeo, showError);
};
</script>
```

Comment: How are you navigating to this page?

Comment: Adrian, I just made an edit and added the code that holds the Check in and out buttons that create the record. Maybe this will help you. I can also post the class if youd like. I am just unsure what you mean by "navigating to this page". It is just a Tab in our Lightning that we put VF components into

Answer (score 1):

If there is no Id specified, the standard controller assumes an insert operation. If you want to supply an Id for update, use the `Id` parameter.

```
<instance>.salesforce.com/apex/<page_name>?Id=<id_value>
```

Replace the placeholder values in angle brackets (`<>`) with actual values from your org.